# Change parent property in tree structure data by Recursive call in js

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, object, tree

I am having the following object

```
let obj = {children:[
{
    ID:1,
    clicked: false,
    children: [
        {
            ID:4,
            clicked: false,
            children: [
                {
                    ID:11,
                    clicked: false,
                    children: [
                                {
                                    ID:14,
                                    clicked: true,
                                },
                                {
                                    ID:15,
                                    clicked: false,
                                }
                            ]
                },
                {
                    ID:12,
                    clicked: false,
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            ID:5,
            clicked: false,
        }
    ]
  }
 ]
}
```

I need to change the clicked property to true of a parent. so in this case ID - 14 is having clicked property to true. So, parents having ID 11,4,1 will also be having the same property to true.

In my understanding, DFS will be applied.
I have tried the following code but not working in all cases

```
function reverseIt(obj) {
  if(obj.children == undefined) {
      return obj.clicked;
  }

  for(i = 0; i < obj.children.length; i++) {
    if(!obj.children[i].clicked) {
        obj.children[i].clicked = reverseIt(obj.children[i]);
    }
    return obj.children[i].clicked;
  }
  return true;
}
reverseIt(obj);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try

```
let reverseIt = o=> o.children ? 
  o.clicked=o.children.reduce((a,c)=>a||o.clicked||reverseIt(c),!1) : o.clicked;
```

```js
let obj={children:[{ID:1,clicked:false,children:[{ID:4,clicked:false,children:[{ID:11,clicked:false,children:[{ID:14,clicked:true},{ID:15,clicked:false}]},{ID:12,clicked:false}]},{ID:5,clicked:false}]}]};

let reverseIt = o=> o.children ? o.clicked=o.children.reduce((a,c)=>a||o.clicked||reverseIt(c),!1) : o.clicked;

// TEST
reverseIt(obj);
console.log(obj);
```

Comment: Thanks @Kamil Kiełczewski :-) working for now. tested 5-6 test cases. Working like a charm.

Comment: Having one problem. Could you please check by making clicked of ID:11 to true then, in that case, it is making all parent false. I think it is working only when the last child is having the value true.
If it is in middle it should follow the same for the parent.

Comment: @VikasChauhan yes you are right - I made fix and update snippet

Comment: can you make to work for multiple objects.
like {children:[
{},{}
]
}

Comment: @VikasChauhan I don't understand - can you provide ID for which solution not working?

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your function slightly:

```js
let obj = {
  children: [{
    ID: 1,
    clicked: false,
    children: [{
        ID: 4,
        clicked: false,
        children: [{
            ID: 11,
            clicked: false,
            children: [{
                ID: 14,
                clicked: true,
              },
              {
                ID: 15,
                clicked: false,
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            ID: 12,
            clicked: true,
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        ID: 5,
        clicked: false,
      }
    ]
  }]
};

function reverseIt(obj) {
  if (!obj.children) {
    return obj;
  }
  if (obj.children.some(c => c.children)) {
    obj.children = obj.children.map(child => reverseIt(child));
  }
  obj.clicked = obj.children[0].clicked;
  return obj;
}
console.log(reverseIt(obj));
```

Comment: I have edited my question. There is only one can be true at a time so suppose the only ID - 12 is true in that case 4,1 will also be true. not working on your solution.

just change any child and look if all the parents are affected or not.

Comment: Sorry @VikasChauhan, I don't understand - 12 is true, and so are 4 and 1 - is this not what you want? Please elaborate on what you want.

Comment: change clicked property of ID:12 in the given object all other clicked to false. The solution should give its parent (having ID 4 and 1) will also be having clicked to true.
This should be generic in all cases. for any child, its parents will be having clicked to true.

is it clear?